# Is there any workaround for using channel name with dash character using spring integration 4 without xml?

Tags: spring-integration

I upgraded my spring integration 3.x to 4.x. And I removed all xml configuration and replace to java annotation in pojo files. But the problem is..

I want to use the channel name with '-' character. It is very good to recognize and distinguish each words in name. Besides, if the dash character is include, I can be sure it is a channel.

But, using dash character in naming method is not allowed. How can I solve this situation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed the simple hook from Spring Annotation configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "my-channel-with-dashes")
public MessageChannel myMessageChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not accustomed with it even if I use it for a long time. haha!~